# asp.net Dropdown menu does not show all the texts In IE,when the text is too long the rest get cut off

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript

asp.net Dropdown menu does not show all the texts In IE,when the text is too long the rest get cut off,anyone can suggest any fixes for it.It works ok in firefox.

Comment: Could you post some sample code??

Comment: What is getting cut off? Width? Height? This sounds like a CSS problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hai ,
 Try Setting Width to your asp dropdown menu

Comment: It looks pretty ugly and the user has to click twice.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/04e20cfd-44a2-4f06-a87f-c39a69a172bb